# JavaScript: Best practices

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I have JS function : Func1 which create some dialog with only 1 button "OK" (for example). What are the best practices to write another one function Func2 that create the same dialog as Func1 but with additional button "Cancel" ?

Create 1 function with parametr(flag) which would show to add button Cancel or not;
Create 2 functions;
Create 3 functions ( 1st would containe all common logic, others would call 1st function and add unique logic only for that functions);

Any other suggestions? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why not allow you to pass in an array of names/functions that create buttons with click events? now you have one function that generates a dialog with a variable number of buttons. Default it to an array with a single "Ok" button that dismisses the dialog. see http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog#option-buttons

Comment: I'd use a function with a flag only for internal things, not on a public api.

Comment: @KevinB and if it's about some html (div, containers, etc.)?

Comment: The content of the dialog?

Comment: @KevinB content - i mean  some html which add some buttons, text or text fields in dialog.

Comment: That's usually the div that you call the plugin on. Just add content to it like you would any other div.